# Django - order_by по функции

Tags: python, django

В Django-проекте существуют 2 модели - **User** и **Task**:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    points = models.FloatField()
    performer = models.ForeignKey(User)


class User(models.Model):
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=11, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def get_points(self):
        points = 0
        for task in Task.objects.filter(performer=user):
            points += task.points
        return points
```

Необходимо найти первых 10 пользователей, сортированных по количеству баллов. Существует ли возможность использовать что-то вроде такого: `top_users = User.objects.order_by(fun=get_points)[:10]`?

Comment: Понимаю, что ваш вопрос уже был задан давно, но все же поинтересуюсь.. Вы смогли решить эту проблему? Сейчас столкнулась с такой же ситуацией.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, так сделать нельзя. order_by будет превращен в строку SQL, и функция на python там не имеет смысла.

В вашем случае можно составить такой запрос:

```
from django.db.models import Sum
top_users = User.objects.annotate(Sum('task__points')).order_by('-task__points__sum')[:10]
```

он будет делать именно то, что вы хотите.

Comment: К сожалению, так сделать нельзя, так как в классе `User` нет поля `task`.

Comment: У модели Task есть поле performer, которое смотрит на модель User. Поэтому для модели User будет существовать обратное отношение task, через которое вы сможете добраться до всех полей модели Task. Попробуйте, это работает.